# What does "roll" mean in the context of hardwood flooring?

Tags: hardwood-floor

I am trying to follow [these instructions](http://www.diynetwork.com/how-to/how-to-install-a-hardwood-floor/index.html#step7) for hardwood flooring installation.  I do not understand what they mean by "nail the rolls".  I cannot think of anything related to hardwood flooring that would resemble a roll.  Can anyone please explain what is mean by this terminology?

> Step 7: Hand-Nail the Rolls
>
> After the first few rows have been installed, drill pilot holes down into the tongue of each board and hand-nail the rolls until there is enough clearance for the pneumatic nail gun.

Source: http://www.diynetwork.com/how-to/how-to-install-a-hardwood-floor/index.html#step7

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a typo for *rows*. Perhaps it was transcribed from a voice recording.

Comment: That's just what is going on. Swap the word rolls for rows, it fits with the  context of the sentence. Always looses something in the translation....